# EXC_BAD_ACCESS signal

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, memory-management, nsarray, exc-bad-access

I have a method start that is hooked up to a button in IB, and basically, the first time I run it, everything works fine, but when I run it second time (and I assure you nothing else happens to the data in between), I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS after the first loop (int i).  I turned on NSZombieEnabled and it doesn't tell me anything, I just simple get a plain

> Program received signal: 
>   “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”. sharedlibrary
>   apply-load-rules all

Here's the method:

```
- (IBAction)start:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"1");
    NSArray* firstArr = [data objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"2");
    for (int i=1; i < [data count]; i++) {
        NSLog(@"%@", data);
        NSArray* currArray = [data objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString* fileName = [currArray objectAtIndex:[firstArr indexOfObject:@"UseFile"]];
        NSString* filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@", fileName];
        NSString* saveAs = [currArray objectAtIndex:[firstArr indexOfObject:@"SaveFileAs"]];
        NSLog(@"3");
        for (int j=0; j < [firstArr count]; j++) {
            NSLog(@"4");
            if ([self isIndexIdentifier:j]) {
                NSLog(@"5");
                NSString* searchStr = [firstArr objectAtIndex:j];
                NSString* replaceStr = [currArray objectAtIndex:j];
                NSDictionary* error;
                NSLog(@"6");
                NSString* appleScript = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                                         @"set searchstring to \"%@\"\n"
                                         @"set replacestring to \"%@\"\n"

                                         @"tell application \"QuarkXPress\"\n"
                                         @"activate\n"
                                         @"if (not (exists document \"%@\")) then\n"
                                         @"open POSIX file \"%@\" with Suppress All Warnings\n"
                                         @"end if\n"
                                         @"tell document \"%@\"\n"
                                         @"repeat with tb from 1 to count of text box\n"
                                         @"tell text box tb\n"
                                         @"set (every text where it is searchstring) to replacestring\n"
                                         @"end tell\n"
                                         @"end repeat\n"
                                         @"end tell\n"
                                         @"end tell\n",
                                         searchStr, replaceStr, fileName, filePath, fileName];
                NSLog(@"7");

                NSLog(@"%@", appleScript);

                NSLog(@"8");
                NSAppleScript *script = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource: appleScript];
                NSLog(@"9");
                [script executeAndReturnError:&error];
                NSLog(@"10");
                [script release];
                NSLog(@"11");
                NSLog(@"%@", error);
            }
        }
    }
```

}

I NSLogged it to see if maybe I can find something and here's the console the **second time** the method gets called:

```
run
2011-04-02 08:55:38.145 TestUI[4472:a0f] 1
2011-04-02 08:55:38.145 TestUI[4472:a0f] 2
2011-04-02 08:55:38.146 TestUI[4472:a0f] (
        (
        UseFile,
        xxxxxxxxxxxxx,
        SaveFileAs
    ),
        (
        "1.qxp",
        11111,
        ""
    ),
        (
        "2.qxp",
        aslkvknv,
        ""
    ),
        (
        "3.qxp",
        ABCDEFG,
        ""
    ),
        (
        "4.qxp",
        222222222,
        ""
    ),
        (
        "5.qxp",
        asdf,
        adsffdsa
    )
)
2011-04-02 08:55:38.146 TestUI[4472:a0f] 3
2011-04-02 08:55:38.147 TestUI[4472:a0f] 4
2011-04-02 08:55:38.147 TestUI[4472:a0f] 4
2011-04-02 08:55:38.147 TestUI[4472:a0f] 5
2011-04-02 08:55:38.147 TestUI[4472:a0f] 6
2011-04-02 08:55:38.148 TestUI[4472:a0f] 7
2011-04-02 08:55:38.148 TestUI[4472:a0f] set searchstring to "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
set replacestring to "11111"
tell application "QuarkXPress"
activate
if (not (exists document "1.qxp")) then
open POSIX file "/1.qxp" with Suppress All Warnings
end if
tell document "1.qxp"
repeat with tb from 1 to count of text box
tell text box tb
set (every text where it is searchstring) to replacestring
end tell
end repeat
end tell
end tell
2011-04-02 08:55:38.148 TestUI[4472:a0f] 8
2011-04-02 08:55:38.148 TestUI[4472:a0f] 9
2011-04-02 08:55:38.517 TestUI[4472:a0f] 10
2011-04-02 08:55:38.517 TestUI[4472:a0f] 11
Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
(gdb)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your final NSLog (of `error`) may well be what's crashing in the output you've pasted. The docs for the `errorInfo` parameter of `executeAndReturn:` say:

> On return, ***if an error occurs***, a pointer to an error information dictionary.

(emphasis added). So if there's no error, there's no guarantee that your uninitialized `error` variable isn't a garbage pointer.

Comment: Thanks both of you, that was the problem! I commented it out and it didn't crash, but how can I tell if an error occurred then? I tried if(error != nil) nslog.... but it crashes. Do I have to set the error to nil when I create it? Isn't it automatically nil? If it's not nil, then what is it set to? Anyways, thanks once again.

Comment: You should set it to nil when you create it. It's not automatically nil; that's true only of member variables, not local variables. Uninitialized variables are set to whatever random value happened to be in that piece of memory, which is why you got different results on different runs.

Comment: @user635064: Generally you're supposed to check the return value of the function to which you passed the error pointer first, and _only_  _if_ that return indicates an error occurred should you try to use the error pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running your app with the Zombies Instrument?
Your problem is very likely an over-release of `data` and Instruments should uncover that.
If the "Zombie Detected" message pops up, click on the memory address and show the extended details panel. (View → Extended Detail)

Comment: The question says that user635064 already tried `NSZombieEnabled`, which does the same thing, just without all the nice facilities for further investigation. If the problem were a message to a deallocated object, either one would prove that.